# How to receive the streamed gzip response from node in Angular2

Tags: node.js, angular

Currently, node streamed my file log1.tar.gz and created a new one directly on the server side. I want to send the `gzip` back to the Angular2 client as an attachment, but I don't know why the client can't get it. And form the Chrome, I checked the request headers, shows:Provisional headers are shown.

Here is my server-side code:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  let file = fs.createReadStream('./log1.tar.gz')
    .pipe(zlib.createGzip())
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./get_logs11.tar.gz'))

  req.on('response', (res) => {
    res.writeHeader(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-zip',
      'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
      'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=myFile.zip',
    });
   res.pipe(file)
  })
 });
```

Client use Angular:
`

```
 public downloadLogs(path) {
    this.http.get(`http://localhost:4200/jsonrpc/download? 
      path=${path}`).toPromise()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('data after download', data)
    })
  ` .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
  }
```

`
I never get the data from client. Anyone knows why? Thanks!

Comment: What is the point of doing `req.on('response', (res) => {`

Comment: I think it means when I get request I want to write header and stream response back. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you should remove that line completely and try again. If you try to debug your script, that callback is probably never getting call.